# google sheet upload to GCS button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-cloud-storage

I have to create a scripted button in my google sheet to upload it as CSV into GCS(buckets).

I have found a nice example documentation but i see there is API keys in it:

https://www.labnol.org/code/20074-upload-files-to-google-cloud-storage

I would like to avoid putting API keys in my Google Apps Script.

Is there a way to perform this and how configure it ?

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) to store and retrieve application info (e.g. `CLIENT_ID`, `CLIENT_SECRET`) without hardcoding it in your script:

- [setProperty(key, value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#getpropertykey)
- [getProperty(key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setProperty(String,String))